# Calculate Overtime based on a sum of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, if-statement

I would like to calculate hours worked that are over 40 per week.

```
table = shift_log_data
database = shift_logs

Field           Type            Null    Key     Default     Extra   
id              int(100)        NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment
admin_hrs       decimal(20,2)   NO              0.00    
shop_hrs        decimal(20,2)   NO              0.00    
fab_hrs         decimal(20,2)   NO              0.00    
paint_hrs       decimal(20,2)   NO              0.00    
vacation_hrs    decimal(50,2)   NO              0.00    
control_hrs     decimal(20,2)   NO              0.00    
test_hrs        decimal(20,2)   NO              0.00    
engine_hrs      decimal(20,2)   NO              0.00    
hydraulic_hrs   decimal(20,2)   NO              0.00    
699_paint       varchar(100)    NO              0.00    
699_shop        varchar(100)    NO              0.00    
maint_hrs       varchar(100)    NO              0.00    
date            date            NO              NULL    
name            varchar(50)     NO              NULL    
job             varchar(50)     NO              NULL
```

Need the columns `admin_hrs` through `maint_hrs` total per week using the date field.
If hours are greater than 40 hours per week, make an alias called overtime showing the rest of the hours greater than forty.

I have tried.

```
SELECT SUM(overtime)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT name,
           IF(SUM(test_hrs+fab_hrs+control_hrs+shop_hrs+paint_hrs+engine_hrs+hydraulic_hrs)>40,
             SUM(test_hrs+fab_hrs+control_hrs+shop_hrs+paint_hrs+engine_hrs+hydraulic_hrs))-40,
              0) AS overtime 
      FROM shift_log_data
     GROUP BY name
  ) TOTAL_OVERTIME
```

Comment: _"...`admin_hrs` through `maint_hrs`..."_ -- `maint_hrs` is a `varchar`, not a number. So are `699_paint` and `699_shop`.  This does not make sense.

Comment: What is the actual problem with your solution? Is there a syntax error? Is the computed result wrong?

Comment: Some critiques of table design - `name` is not a unique identifier for a person, you'll want some sort of unique person id fk to a `person` table.  You probably also want a `job` table for roughly similar reasons.  This table should probably be normalized so there's a single `hours_worked` field (or maybe `minutes_worked`, as an hour doesn't divide cleanly into base 10 fractions), with an `hour_type` field.  Why are **vacation** hours being counted in the total?  That sounds exploitable.  Alternatively, have a table with a clockin/out time (and type).  And which is it, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: The computed results are not correct. It is not grouping per week or calculation overtime per week.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.Name, YEAR(s.Date), WEEKOFYEAR(s.date),
      IF(SUM(test_hrs+fab_hrs+control_hrs+shop_hrs+paint_hrs+engine_hrs+hydraulic_hrs)>40,
          SUM(test_hrs+fab_hrs+control_hrs+shop_hrs+paint_hrs+engine_hrs+hydraulic_hrs))-40,
          0
         ) AS overtime 
FROM shift_log_data s
GROUP BY s.Name, YEAR(s.Date), WEEKOFYEAR(s.date);
```